# ASP.NET Core Redirect to Action using custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Inside the ASP.NET Core web application I want to redirect unauthorized users to some page. I know it can be done via "LoginPath" attribute from Startup.cs, but I want it to work only on one specific controller. So I tried to create AuthorizationHandler descendant, but I think it is impossible to redirect to action from there. Any advice how this can be solved?

To make it clearer:

```
 protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SelfAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
       if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          #redirect here
    }
```

Comment: What did you tried in the AuthroizationHandler and why do you think it's impossible? You got to show something that you have put in some investment in trying to solve it yourself ;)

Comment: Make filter with check if auth and if not make redirect

Comment: @Tseng I tried lots of searching about how to do that, but couldn't find anything close to what I want, that's why I'm posting here. What else do you want me to 'Put investment' into? :))) Oh anyway thank you very much for teaching me that I have to try at first myself :))

Comment: @J.Doe I am not having problem with checking if authorized, I am having problem with redirect. How to make redirect from AuthorizationHandler that's what I am asking.

Comment: It's still not clear what you really want. Every Authorize attribute has a scheme and every authentication middleware can be set with a specific scheme, which will be evaluated by the middleware which handles this scheme. And per middleware per scheme you can set the LoginPath. So where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `[Authorize]` attribute to action and set in `startup.cs` options identity with your patch to login. For exaple:

```
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "LoginPath";
    });
```

More in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration)